# Vagrant machine on VirtualBox won't boot due to VERR_SUP_VP_THREAD_NOT_ALONE

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, vagrant

The boot does not work.

Vagrant: 2.2.0

VirtualBox: 5.2.22
Windows 10

Git BASH: mintty 2.9..6 (x86_64-pc-msys)

Oracle error Here: [image]

Here rais the error code on Git BASH:

```
$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Checking if box 'centos/7' is up to date...
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
    default: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> default: Booting VM...
There was an error while executing `\VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["startvm", "5147f0f3-1ef4-49aa-bb1b-f5ddd90be508", "--type", "headless"]

Stderr: VBoxManage.exe: error: The virtual machine 'aw-backend' has terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit code 1 (0x1).  More details may be available in 'C:\Users\home\VirtualBox VMs\aw-backend\Logs\VBoxHardening.log'
VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code E_FAIL (0x80004005), component MachineWrap, interface IMachine
```

I also tried (virtual) Windows-7, Mac-OS, Fedora, and Ubuntu with the same result. Same results.

Comment: Is your issue related to this one? https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=83791&sid=4b543edab92a5c4a2ac0ddd68be1a6c6
The people at the VirtualBox forums found that some antivirus/firewalls may not play nice with hardened VirtualBox.

Comment: I tried most of there; no luck... Thanks anyway.

Comment: If you did so, then it would be nice to put in the question what things have already tried (and what not), and software that you have that may be at fault here. Otherwise nobody can distinguish your question from others alike